# sp_execute SQL vs exec

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic, sql-server-2000

as i have read in the following blog...

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

dynamic sql is unsafe, that's why we have sp_execute SQL.

could i ask, is there any way to make sp_execute run a procedure like this...

```
declare @QueryMain as varchar(8000)
declare @QueryBody as varchar(8000)
declare @QueryWhere as varchar(8000)

set @QueryMain = <8000 charactes>
set @QueryBody = <8000 characters>
set @QueryWhere = <8000 characters>

exec (@queryMain+@QueryBody+@QueryWhere)
```

this would run, but as i have read in the article, it is not recommended... but i would like to know if there is another way to run this kind of query... i tried to incorporate the 3 variables to ntext but it didnt worked, and btw... the example query above would have other variables inside there query which could be dates, userIDs, anything!

i am using sql server 2000 btw... and as i have googled, i found no results how to manipulate large strings for sql server 2000, but i have this consequence of the SQLi attack.

Comment: Why do you want to run this kind of query? You will always have the actual SQL statement because you are building it. Are you trying to get this to run from a piece of code?

Comment: @twoleggedhorse because i  am migrating every sql script from a system to stored procedures, the sql scripts are, tested by me, vulnerable to sql injections. they we legacy systems developed by past programmers, and have ignored the risk of this kind of threat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking if you can do this:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @QueryMain + @QueryBody + @QueryWhere;
```

No, you cannot have expressions or formulas as parameter values. But why do you need to? The workaround is simple, just append them in an intermediate variable (and this should be `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, not `NTEXT` which is both deprecated and isn't valid for local variables):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

...

SET @sql = @QueryMain + @QueryBody + @QueryWhere;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

In fact all of these variables should be `NVARCHAR`.

See [this post for some more on `EXEC` vs. `sp_executesql`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql).

Comment: @Aaron_bertrand the reason why i didnt go with nvarchar(max) is because we only have sql server 2000, and this version does not support the nvarchar(max) yet, i'm migrating every sql script embedded from the system to stored procedures, and lessen the risk of sql injections

Comment: @Joshua sorry, I missed the SQL Server 2000 tag. However I think you're giving yourself a false sense of security... why do you think glomming a bunch of non-validated text and executing using sp_executesql will be safer then using EXEC? The reason sp_executesql is safer is because it promotes the use of strongly-typed parameters, not because it magically prevents injection in and of itself. You are not intending to use it in a way that helps IMHO, so just keep using EXEC.

Comment: @Aaron_bertrand thank you sir for the clarification, i really would like to learn more. thank you for the knowledge sir!